# What privelges do I need to run wlan report on windows 10

Tags: administrator, netsh

I have started a powershell/cmd session with admin priveledges and run

```
netsh wlan show wlanreport
```

but it tells me that

```
You must run this command from a command prompt with administrator
privilege.
```

[image]

```
Why does this not work? My OS spec is
```

[image]

Comment: The titles have changed since 1709: is this `cmd` run from the Administrator account, or run with administrator privileges from the normal user account? The latter works on 1709.

Comment: My account is "Local Adminstrator". I open up powershell or cmd from the start menu with right click. "run as administrator" I then type in the problematic netsh command

Comment: I believe that there are quite a few problems with 1803, which have stopped me from upgrading. This may be one of them. Maybe someone with 1803 will be able to help.